# DataTypes when creating an xls worksheet with OLEDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, oledb

I have a `ASP.NET 4.0 web app` which reads data from a `SQL Server 2008 R2` into a `DataSet`. Now I want to write this data into an `xls` file (Office 2003). At the moment, I create a empty worksheet using `CREATE TABLE`, and write the data into it row by row using insert statements. But what I really want is the colunmns in the excel file to be formated according to the datatyp from the data set. For example, if the field in the dataset is of system.decimal type, I want the corresponding column in excel to be formatted as a decimal.

So far, I have tried different datatypes within my `CREATE TABLE statement`. I tries `SQL datatypes` (int, bigint, money, datetime, bit, nvarchar and xml are the ones my database uses most), and I have also tried several `Excel-specific datatypes` as well as several `OleDB` specific ones, but without success. The data is written into the file, but the columns remain formatted as default.

Some detailed information:

```
String AceConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=YES; IMEX=0; READONLY=FALSE;\""; //filename is the target xls file

**example CREATE TABLE statement (with SQL datatypes for the fields)**

CREATE TABLE [Report22.10.2013 14:45] ([IDKatalog] Int, [KatalogName] NVarChar(255), [Tabellenname] NVarChar(255), [KomplettUpdate] Bit, [IDLieferant] Int, [FreigabeVon] NVarChar(255), [FreigabeVonEMail] NVarChar(255), [IDKatalogAS] Int)
```

Is it event possible to set the formation using `OLEDB` ? I know you cannot change the data representation like color, fonts, width, ect, but can I determain the cell format ?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if it is possible to do this in OLEDB, but it certainly can be done using Powershell or VBA. The following is from Microsoft's reference.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A17").NumberFormat = "General"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C"). _
NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224873%28v=office.11%29.aspx

If you don't want to use Powershell, you can also try pre-making template files with the proper formatting information already put in and then have OLEDB fill that out and save the populated sheet as something else.